# ZF2 - Access collection values in the view

Tags: collections, zend-framework2

I would like to access an array of values that has been populated in my fieldset.

In the controller I populate and array and add it to my model before calling the .phtml.  I know the data is there (print_r/var_dump shows it) but I don't know how to access it.

Example of the var_dump:

```
    ["object":protected]=>
    object(Instrument\Model\EFMultiEquip)#337 (5) {
      ["iadid"]=>
        string(7) "ABI3130"
      ["featureset"]=>
        NULL
      ["availfeatures"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["availfeatureset"]=>
            array(10) {
             [0]=>
               array(4) {
                 ["ibacode"]=>
                 string(3) "C3I"
                 ["ibadesc"]=>
                 string(16) "Jouan centrifuge"
                 ["ibacost"]=>
                 string(4) "5.00"
                 ["ibafeatime"]=>
                 string(1) "0"
               }
```

I need to access the "availfeatureset" array.  I've tried all kinds of gets but this data just eludes me.  If any of you have an idea on how to go about accessing the data I'd appreciate it.

Vaughn

Comment: RESOLVED:  In my Fieldset definition, the type attribute for my collections has to be moved to within the options array.  Once done, I was able to get hold of the data.

Comment: Write your solution as an answer, or consider to delete your Question. Imo this has been quite a localised problem ;)